# Azure Logic Apps -- HTTP Action -- POST Error

Tags: http, post, azure-logic-apps

So I am trying to get an authorization token from MSFT.
I am using the HTTP Request object as an action.
I set the method to POST, provide URI, set a Content_Type in the Header, and add a grant type to the body.
[Screenshot of LogicApps HTTP Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArQ7q.png)

When I run my logic app I receive the following error:

```
"error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: ef137edb-87d4-43e2-88b7-d119b2c00500\r\nCorrelation ID: 4ea88c05-7f28-4e3f-bb31-052c3baac198\r\nTimestamp: 2020-05-22 17:33:21Z",
  "error_codes": [
    900144
```

So the error says I am missing 'grant_type' but I have it in the body.

Can anyone point me in a direction to get this resolved?

Comment: Hi, has this problem been solved ? May I know what do you want to do(which api do you want to request) with the token you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Body in this case is not a JSON object, it's a Form encode. Here's a screen shot where I do this same task:

[image]

You'll need to pass the client_id and client_secret as well.

Comment: I still get the same error. Now, the only thing is I have the values for my client_id and client_secret, instead of using "value" I tried parameters and variables, instead of the long strong but that still didn't work

Comment: Did you include the "$resource..." section as well?

Comment: there was something odd with my code, when I started from scratch, and made sure I included all that it worked.